# iterate through firebase storage to display multiple images

Tags: javascript, firebase

Currently I am able to fetch a specific picture knowing its title and location in the storage,  but I want to be able to show all pictures in one folder inside my storage knowing the location of that storage folder but not the content titles.

I have tried using the below code (projectID is the folder which I need to show all the elements of) but it doesn't seem to work.  I am new to javascript so I apologize for the wrong function call of .once.

```js
const childRef = storageRefer.child(`${projectID}`);
childRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      console.log(url);
    });
  });
});
```

this code should be able to log the url of all the images but all I get is an error about the .once function.  If anyone knows what I am doing wrong or a better method in getting all the images in one folder inside my storage that would be super helpful, thanks!

**Edit:**

Looking back at this I realized I could store the location of the images into a database for them as I can easily iterate through a database without knowing what is inside and call to storage to get the image, but that seems sloppy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no API call in Firebase Storage to list all files in a folder. If you need such functionality, you should store the metadata of the files (such as the download URLs) in a place where you can list them. The Firebase Firestore is perfect for this and allows you to also easily share the URLs with others.

Comment: I see how this would work but I seem to be getting an error of `Uncaught TypeError: childRef.once is not a function`, do you know why this might be?  I apologize again as I am used to languages like python and java and not so used to javascript.

Comment: what is storageRefer? You cannot directly download file from storage instead access its url from documents and call image

Comment: sorry about that, `const storage = firebase.storage(); const storageRefer = storage.ref();` is defined in a script statement imbedded directly into my html so I can call it from any of my javascript files, what do you mean by accessing an image from the documents?  I am able to get an image directly using a function such as `storageRefer.child('${projectID}').child("horse.jpg").getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {document.querySelector("#imgUpload").setAttribute("src", url)});`

Comment: what do you get on console.log of childRef?

Comment: Firebase Storage is built on Google Cloud Storage, which does precisely what you say: it stores all objects in one long list. Firebase Storage models a hierarchy on top of that, admittedly as a leaky abstraction. The common reasons for using folder in Firebase Storage are for logical data separation and for crafting security rules based on the folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was hoping there would be a way to get that information as you can in the databases because then it wouldn't require double storing information

Answer (score 2):

```
 var listRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('profiles/');


  listRef.listAll().then(function(res){
     res.items.forEach(function(itemRef){
      itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (link) {
        console.log(link);
      })
    
   })
 })
}
```

This function brings all photos saved in the storage "Profile"
I hope it works for you.

Comment: Welcome! Using English language is sort of expected in SO posts.

Comment: Oh, please, sorry. I didn't realize I commented in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

@Shodmoth Check out this new firebase link (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files) for how to list all the files in a folder.

```
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var listRef = storageRef.child('files/uid');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
  res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
     console.log(folderRef)
  });
  res.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
     console.log(itemRef) //can call .getDownloadURL() on each itemRef
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```